[AppGalleryConnectPublishService]Incomplete application version information
I'm trying to upload an android apps to huawei referring to this website
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-app-submit-0000001158245061
I try in postman, the error code would give me 204144641 - [AppGalleryConnectPublishService]Incomplete application version information, what is this means?
Below is the cUrl
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJraWQiOiIyUFA5b0lMcElmOTRtUFZVN3RlTkJSZkU3OEFVVWJPMSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImFsZyI6IkhTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiIxNTczMTcyMDI4MDI0ODQxOTg0IiwiZG4iOjEsImNsaWVudF90eXBlIjoxLCJleHAiOjE3MzM5OTYwNDksImlhdCI6MTczMzgyMzI0OX0.lJfGkNiOTTl-pAkxIMRc5F_jPVmyLZ0MuaPgx36Bt1E' \
--header 'client_id: 15731720**********' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "phasedReleaseStartTime": "2024-12-11T00:00:00+0000",
    "phasedReleaseEndTime": "2024-12-25T23:59:59+0000",
    "phasedReleasePercent": "100.00",
    "phasedReleaseDescription": "Open testing release"
}'```



